# Does XSLT on the client side hurt SEO

Tags: seo

I am planning to offload some processing to the client via client side XSLT. I would like to know if I do this will it hurt my seo rankings?

Answer (score 3):

I think it will. a good solution would be to render and html on your server instead of client.
it is well known that google does index xml pages, but still "prefers" html.

Answer (score 1):

Does a search engine parse the XML using the XSLT? If not, it will only see the XML and has no idea what's important and what is not. It just looks like plain text.